# What does it mean to "reduce to the case"?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, terminology, propositional-calculus

Suppose we have a statement we need to prove: If $p$ then $q$.

If we are told "reduce to the case where $r$", **what does this mean?**

Is this saying that the statement "$p$ implies $q$" follows from "$r$ implies $q$", and so we only need to prove the statement: If $r$ then $q$?

Comment: It depends. If it's the author of a book or article explaining a proof, then it just means that the author is claiming, with or without proof, $[((p\land r)\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow (p\Rightarrow q)]$, and that he will henceforth prove $[p\Rightarrow q]$ by means of proving $[(p\land r)\Rightarrow q]$. If it's in an assignment it means that the author is suggesting that you should prove $[p\Rightarrow q]$ by means of proving both $[((p\land r)\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow (p\Rightarrow q)]$ and $[(p\land r)\Rightarrow q]$.

Comment: Example: I want to prove that a real-valued degree-3 polynomial $f(x)=a_3 x^3\,+\,{a_2} x^2\,+\,{a_1} x\,+\,{a_0}$ must have a root/zero. Say coefficients are real and $a_3$ is not zero. We can reduce this to the case $a_3 = 1$. Because, then we can apply the special theorem to $\frac{f(x)}{a_3}$, and get the full theorem.

Comment: @Gae.S. That clarifies it.